# List Comprehensions in Functions, Python

Tags: python

I want to create a function where I input a List (with lower case and upper case strings), the function will then make any uppercase strings lower case and output the list again. I tried using list comprehension, but not sure how I can assign a variable to this/ if there are any easier ways to do this?

```
def lowerlist(inputList):
    [x.lower() for x in inputList]
    print inputList 

inputList = ["Red", "green", "Blue"]
lowerList(inputList)
```

Comment: i initially started by creating the list to a string and then lower casing it, but then ran into the issue of making this back into a list. can I do it this way too (relatively elegantly?)

Comment: Yes, you can but a list comprehension is nice too! No? And is very efficient!

Comment: I see that as a good solution,  you can return the modified list from the method : `return [x. lower() for x in inputList]`

Answer (score 1):

Just `return` your list comp, use `inputList[:] =  lower_list(input_list)` to update your original list with the updated return values:

```
def lower_list(inp):
    return [x.lower() for x in inp]


input_list = ["Red", "green", "Blue"]

input_list[:] =  lower_list(input_list)
```

Or using map:

```
input_list = ["Red", "green", "Blue"]
input_list[:] =  map(str.lower,input_list)
```

The `[:]` syntax means you actually update the values in your original list/object, you could also return a generator expression:

```
 def lower_list(inp):
    return (x.lower() for x in inp)
```

And use it the same way:

```
 input_list = ["Red", "green", "Blue"]
 input_list[:] =  lower_list(input_list)
```

Comment: What [:] stands for? Can't you just input_list = whatever? I know of structures like list[0:5], etc, but here I just don't understand its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You can just return the newly created list :

```
def lowerlist(inputList):
    return [x.lower() for x in inputList]

inputList = ["Red", "green", "Blue"]
resultList = lowerlist(inputList)
```

By the way, a list comprehension create a new list, it does not change a list in-place, so if you do something like :

```
[x.lower() for x in inputList]
```

You are not modifying `inputList`, but creating a new list (you can then return this list and assign it)

Answer (score 0):

Except list comprehension does not change the list in place (at least as of python 2.7), so you need:

```
 print "{0}, ".format([x.lower() for x in inputList])
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension returns a list, so something like

```
lowercaseStrings = [x.lower() for x in inputList]
```

The list over which you iterate is left unchanged. So inputList will still contain the mix of lowercase and uppercase strings.

To return the lowercase string list, the following would work (as other answers have already stated)

```
def lowerlist(inputList):
    return [x.lower() for x in inputList]
```